# ConcurrentHashMap, which concurrent features improved in JDK8

Tags: concurrency, java-8, concurrenthashmap

Can any concurrent expert explain in ConcurrentHashMap, which concurrent features improved comparing with which in previous JDKs

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, the `ConcurrentHashMap` has been entirely rewritten. Before Java 8, each `ConcurrentHashMap` had a “concurrency level” which was fixed at construction time. For compatibility reasons, there is still a [constructor accepting such a level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#ConcurrentHashMap-int-float-int-) though not using it in the original way. The map was split into as many segments, as its concurrency level, each of them having its own lock, so in theory, there could be up to *concurrency level* concurrent updates, if they all happened to target different segments, which depends on the hashing.

In Java 8, each hash bucket can get updated individually, so as long as there are no hash collisions, there can be as many concurrent updates as its current capacity. This is in line with the new features like the [`compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) methods which guaranty atomic updates, hence, locking of at least the hash bucket which gets updated. In the best case, they lock indeed only that single bucket.

Further, the `ConcurrentHashMap` benefits from the general hash improvements applied to all kind of hash maps. When there are hash collisions for a certain bucket, the implementation will resort to a sorted map like structure within that bucket, thus degrading to a `O(log(n))` complexity rather than the `O(n)` complexity of the old implementation when searching the bucket.

Comment: Hi Holger, ** In Java 8, each hash bucket can get updated individually** As per your answer, In java 8, it locks only the single bucket while updating and not a segment(collection of buckets). But it is same thing as in older java version, We could achieve this by passing concurrency level equal to the  current capacity. It means we can specify 16 threads for 16 buckets. Then what is the difference it is making? I know there is some gap in my understanding. Please correct me.

Comment: @Pradeep Singh: not exactly. The problem is that it depends on the actual key’s hash code, in which segment the mapping will be stored. There is no guaranty that storing *n* keys in a map with *n* segments will end up with one key per segment, in fact, the higher *n* will be the more unlikely a perfect distribution will become. Further, the capacity is not constant, but the number of segments is. So if you initialize a Java 7 `ConcurrentHashMap` with a segment count reflecting the highest capacity the map could ever have, you’ll end up with a giant overhead, perhaps never used.

Comment: Thanks Holger. I understood. :)

Comment: @Holger, what was the benefit of using segments in java 7 or earlier versions? Seems like this design (hash buckets without segments) should have been used since the beginning.

Comment: @aniliitb10 well, that’s what you can say about lots of new inventions. Once they are there, they look so obvious that anyone asks “why didn’t no-one consider this earlier?”. Why didn’t they had the idea of a binary tree to resolve bucket collisions before all these experiments with “alternative hashing”? Why did it take until Java 9 to realize, that most strings still fit into iso-latin-1, so forcing a two byte encoding for all of them is a huge waste?

Comment: @Hogler, so here is why I asked this question: My instructor had told me that in java 7, size() used to take lock over all segments and hence giving the exact count of number of elements in the map (like what hashmap does). Had there been no segments, it would have been almost-impossible to take lock over all hash buckets. So, according to him, this size() was one of the reasons why CHM had segements, otherwise, they would have gone for segment-less design from much before java 8.

Comment: But I just found out that size() has just been an estimate since java 5. So, I am surprised that if size() was not really the reason then what else (design decision) was the reason.

Comment: @aniliitb10 there is not much sense in an “exact size” for a concurrently updated data structure. If you can preclude concurrent updates, e.g. when the multi-threaded operation has ended, all approaches will provide a correct size. If concurrent updates may still happen, the size may be outdated right the moment, `size()` returns, regardless of how precise it ever was. The segmented design is a consequence of the idea of using `Lock` instances to control the access, to avoid the overhead of have a `Lock` for each bucket. The new design combines lock free algorithms and `synchronized` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several changes compared with JDK7:

- Lazy initialization: in JDK8, the memory used for each segment is allocated only when some entity is added to the map. In JDK7,this is done when the map is created.
- Some new function is added in JDK8 like forEach, reduce, search etc.
- Inner structure change : the TreeBin (red-black tree) is used in jdk8 to improve the search efficiency.