# Does ConcurrenthashMap documentation allow to repeat compute method invocations in case of thread competition?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

Lets compare java doc snippets about compute method for interface `ConcurrentMap` and class `ConcurrentHashMap`

`ConcurrentMap`

> The default implementation is equivalent to performing the following
>    steps for this {@code map}, then returning the current value or
>    {@code null} if absent:
>     ...
>    The default implementation **may retry these steps** when multiple
>    threads attempt updates including potentially calling the remapping
>     function multiple times.

`ConcurrenthashMap:`

> Attempts to compute a mapping for the specified key and its current
>   mapped value (or {@code null} if there is no current mapping). The
>   entire method invocation is performed atomically. Some attempted
>   update **operations on this map by other threads may be blocked** while
>   computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and
>   simple, and must not attempt to update any other mappings of this Map.

I understand  that current version of Jdk `ConcurrentHashMap` blocks the full segment and 2 compute actions for keys from same segment can't be executed in parallel but I am not sure can I use this knowledge in my code or not.  In future oracle developers can change ConcurrentHashMap implementation(use CAS instead of blocking).

Please, share your thoughts.

Comment: It's very unlikely they'd break backwards compatibility in such a huge way.

Comment: Doc for ConcurrentHashmap seems detailed enough to answer "No", now and in future. Remember that basic `ConcurrentMap` must support implementations other than ConcurrentHashMap, e.g. skip lists.

As a side note: It sounds like your operation has a side effect, which should be avoided due to complexity and concurrency.

Comment: The current version is JDK8, in which the implementation does *not* “blocks the full segment” as there is no such thing as a segment. It blocks the node, which represents a single key in the best case.

Comment: @Holger can you provide proof?

Comment: Compare the class documentations regarding what they say about “`concurrencyLevel `”: [Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html): *The table is internally partitioned to try to permit the indicated number of concurrent updates without contention*… [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html): *Also, for compatibility with previous versions of this class, constructors may optionally specify an expected concurrencyLevel as an additional hint for internal sizing.*

Comment: You may also compare with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31581438/2711488) or [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java). Note that in this implementation, the class `Segment` has been merely “*declared for the sake of serialization compatibility*”…